# Windows 8 won't recognize audio device on Macbook Pro (late) 2011

Tags: macbook-pro, bootcamp

I just installed Windows 8 on my MacBook Pro, I then installed the Windows Support drivers and everything works great except for one thing, the audio. It doesn't recognize the audio device in my Macbook.

I've tried downloading the Cirrus audio drivers and installing them manually, but it still won't work.

Has anybody had any success getting audio working on a late 2011 MacBook Pro running Windows 8?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it worked for me, however- I had to go back into bootcamp and download the Win setup drivers again and grab them from inside the display folder ( I am assuming from that that they are part of the graphics card). It did not like the ones downloaded from the web.

Answer (score 1):

Windows 8 on a MacBook Pro late 2011 should work. I'm not sure if you have checked on Creating the USB Drive/ Installation Medium on the Bootcamp Assistant to download all the Drivers.

Try to install:

- [Boot Camp Support Software 5.0.5033](http://support.apple.com/kb/DL1638)

If this does not work, check if your Bootcamp Assistant is the newest, but it should normally be, otherwise you wouldn't be able to create a Win8 start Drive.